# Store and sort by distance using latitude and longitude Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, latitude-longitude

I am working in Symfony2 with Doctrine.

I have a database of entities named `Landmarks` where each entity has a `1:many` relationship with a `MapMarker` entity, and it is the `MapMarker` entity which has a `latitude` and `longitude` field, e.g. "Central Park" might be a `Landmark` with many "entrances" which would be stored as `MapMarkers`.

I then have another entity named `Property`, which has a `1:1` relationship with a `MapMarker`.

For any given `Property`, What is the best way to find all the nearby `Landmarks` in the database, sorted by the Landmark's closest `MapMarker`?

In a legacy version of this application, without Doctrine or Symfony2, I was doing it this way:

1. Retrieve all the `Landmarks` in database
2. For each `Landmark`, go through each of its `MapMarkers` in a PHP function and calculate the distance between the P`roperty's MapMarker's lat,lng` and the `Landmarks MapMarker's lat,lng`.
3. If any of the calculated distances was less than or equal to some pre-determined constant I had chosen (say 3km) then I made linked the `Property` to the `Landmark` in a `many:many` relatioship.
4. Later, when querying the database for a `Property's` nearby `Landmarks`, it would go through only the linked `Landmarks`' `MapMarkers` and then calculate, again, the nearest `MapMarker` and distance for presentation like such:

> > Nearby Landmarks to your Property:
>
> - **Central Park**, Main Gate - 2.4km
> - etc.

The benefits of this were that it by creating a permanent link between the `Property` and the `Landmark`, I automatically had a "short-list" of nearby `Landmarks` for which to calculate the expensive distance formula.

However as you likely noticed, problems arise when a new `Landmark` is added, or the `MapMarkers` of a `Landmark` change. Also, it is still quite slow to be calculating the distance every time a `Property` is searched (or reverse if finding all `Properties` by `Landmark`).

Really hoping to come up with a better way now that I am migrating to Symfony2 and Doctrine.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about calculating the max/min lat and lng (e.g. the highest and lowest lat and lng values for 3km in a straight line in the 4 directions) you can then just make a query to the map markers and find the lat and lng between those values.

Comment: Yes, this is one step I included in the solution I came up with! Made a big difference in performance by narrowing the field! Thanks @DerickF

Answer (score 0):

Well Symfony2 and Doctrine won't free you from your usual database / PHP constraints so it is pretty much a matter of adapting your existing logic to it.

With that said and of the top of my head I would probably do something like:

- Join Query the database with a BETWEEN on latitude/longitude (ie: lat between marker_lat + X / marker_lat - X and long between marker_long + X / marker_long - X) to get a short list of close by mapmarkers
- Write a function to calculate distance and keep the closest

Rather than make a whole new table with number of markers * X entries which makes for poor scalability if you ask me but obviously it depends on your application constraints so I can't really think that through for you.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, but it worked out a little complicated in the details.